# Prevent app crash due to Google native library error

Tags: android, google-vision, crash

I have an app uploaded to Google Play that was working fine, but suddenly some users reported me a strange error. I have been investigating and it's due to an [internal error of the google vision inside gms library](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/269). This is the code that causes the problem:

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context)
                .build();
```

This error only occurs on some devices. So how can I handle this error at runtime preventing an app crash?.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: simple `try-catch` is not working?

Comment: No it doesn't catch the error

Answer (score 1):

The API is currently broken on "Samsung Exynos arm64 devices"

Google know about this and will fix it in the next upadte of Google Play Services.

Full message:

"On Google Play Services version 10.7.x you may see crashes when using Text API on Samsung Exynos arm64 devices. This is a known issue and will be fixed in the next release."

Info from: https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the API level of the troubling phones, try making a simple API check before calling this line.
Something like the code below(but with the versions you decide).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
```

`}`

Comment: Depends on the device not on the api level

Comment: and what devices are those?

Comment: I'am having it happen on a Galaxy S7 api level 24

Comment: after research i came to the conclusion that @Lawtonj94 's answer is correct, for now you can check for device name and do the workaround for galaxy S7 or check for all api lvl 24 devices. But anyway, just wait until google fix it :D